# Can \ref make reference to two labels?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I would like to use the `label/ref` mechanism with two labels.

For instance, in this example:

```
\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 1 \label{1}
\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 2 \label{2}
\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 3 \label{3}

\refstepcounter{A}\setcounter{B}{0}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 1 \label{4}
\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 2 \label{5}
\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 3 \label{6}

\ref{1}
\ref{2}
\ref{3}
\ref{4}
\ref{5}
\ref{6}
```

I would like the references to be displayed as `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.3` and then `2.1`, `2.2`, `2.3`.

Is it possible? Is there some package maybe that could help?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}[A]

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 1 \label{1}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 2 \label{2}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 3 \label{3}

\refstepcounter{A}\setcounter{B}{0}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 1 \label{4}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 2 \label{5}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 3 \label{6}

\ref{1}

\ref{2}

\ref{3}

\ref{4}

\ref{5}

\ref{6}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\counterwithin`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\counterwithin{B}{A}

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{A}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 1 \label{1}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 2 \label{2}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 1, B = 3 \label{3}

\refstepcounter{A}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 1 \label{4}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 2 \label{5}

\refstepcounter{B} A = 2, B = 3 \label{6}

\ref{1}

\ref{2}

\ref{3}

\ref{4}

\ref{5}

\ref{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: actually that's better than mine I'll delete (you might mention that you need a package version of that unless you have a newish latex, but either way it's probably better than setting `\p@` directly as I suggested (not that it's any different internally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's been in the kernel for some time already, hasn't it? I can check and add the info, no problem. Previously, it was `varioref`'s or from somewhere else?

Comment: oh 2018 I was thinking it was newer than that, doesn't time fly:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your time perspective in these matters is altogether different from a regular person: 2018 is "just yesterday". ;-)

Comment: well yes, (`chngcntr` is the package)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, yes indeed! Do you still think many people need this hint in the answer proper, or is the comment thread here enough?

Comment: no let it go, if they have a latex older than that, they know they have an old latex:-)

Comment: see how quickly I learn? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637218/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  :-)