# Numbering equations show as '3.1', '3.2', etc

Tags: equations, numbering

I have been struggling with the numbering of my equations in Latex for a bit now.
I have looked at other suggestions, but every method I try, I keep getting a numbering corresponding to '3.1)', '3.2)', etc. For clarification, I would like to have just the '1)', '2)', etc.

```
Then, the direct utility function of the household is: 
\begin{equation} 
  U\{C_{1i}, L_{1i}, C_{2i}, L_{2i} \} 
\end{equation} 

Under the budget constraints:

\begin{equation}
  C_{1i} = w_{1i}h_{1i}  
\end{equation}
```

The output i get is:

[image]

I think it may have to do with the overall numbering in my document. I think it shows the 3 as it's in the third section of the document.

Does somebody know how i should fix this issue? I would be very thankful :)

Comment: it is set by your document class but `\counterwithout{equation}{section}` should reset it

Comment: This worked!! Thanks A LOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is set by your document class but `\counterwithout{equation}{section}` should reset it

Comment: How do you find out about these things? :)